# SQL Server Full Text Search not returning expected results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I installed full-text search for SQL Server, created a catalog and index. I am sure that there are proper records in the database, but FTS functions doesn't return any result.

For example:

```
select * from tablename where contains(title, 'baycan');
select * from tablename where contains(title, '"*baycan*"')
```

This is catalog and index image:

[image]

Comment: If there are no results, that suggests there is no rows with the word `'baycan'` in the column `title`.

Comment: But I can get records by LIKE. So that is  not case

Comment: `LIKE` and `CONTAINS` are not equivalent operators, so just because `LIKE` returns something doesn't mean `CONTAINS` will. For example a column (`title`) with the value `'abaycant'` will return true for `WHERE title LIKE '%baycan%'`, however, `CONTAINS(title,'baycan')` will not.

Comment: aand what is equivalent of this query in FTS --- select * from tablename where title like '%baycan%';

Comment: There isn't one. `CONTAINS` does not support leading wildcards.

Comment: what about FREETEXT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you are misunderstanding `CONTAINS` and `LIKE`, they are *not* equivalent operators. From [CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> CONTAINS can search for:
>
> - **A word or phrase.**
> - **The prefix of a word or phrase.**
> - A word near another word.
> - A word inflectionally generated from another (for example, the word drive is the inflectional stem of drives, drove, driving, and driven).
>
> A word that is a synonym of another word using a thesaurus (for
>   example, the word "metal" can have synonyms such as "aluminum" and
>   "steel").

Emphasis my own.

`CONTAINS` does not support a leading wildcard, only a trailing one. As a result, (as I say in my comment) for a column (`title`) with the value `'abaycant'` the expression `WHERE title LIKE '%baycan%'` will return TRUE, however, `CONTAINS(title,'baycan')` will not.

If you have the value `'baycant'` then `LIKE 'baycan%'` and `CONTAINS(title,'baycan*')` (and `LIKE '%baycan%'`) would all return TRUE; the former 2 would also be SARGable too (the one in parenthesis would not be).

If the value were `'best baycant'` then both `CONTAINS(title,'baycan*')` and  `LIKE '%baycan%'` would return TRUE, but only the former would be SARGable.

This is also further supported later in the argument section in relation to the *phrase* parameter (the second parameter) when using it as a prefix (there is not option in the arguments for suffix or "in the middle of"):

> *`<prefix_term>`*
>
> Specifies a match of words or phrases beginning with the specified
>   text. Enclose a prefix term in double quotation marks ("") and add an
>   asterisk (*) before the ending quotation mark, so that all text
>   starting with the simple term specified before the asterisk is
>   matched. The clause should be specified this way: `CONTAINS (column,
>   '"text*"')`. The asterisk matches zero, one, or more characters (of the
>   root word or words in the word or phrase). If the text and asterisk
>   are not delimited by double quotation marks, so the predicate reads
>   `CONTAINS (column, 'text*')`, full-text search considers the asterisk as
>   a character and searches for exact matches to text*. The full-text
>   engine will not find words with the asterisk (*) character because
>   word breakers typically ignore such characters.
>
> When *`<prefix_term>`* is a phrase, each word contained in the phrase is
>   considered to be a separate prefix. Therefore, a query specifying a
>   prefix term of "local wine*" matches any rows with the text of "local
>   winery", "locally wined and dined", and so on.

`FREETEXT` will not change this. [FREETEXT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> When FREETEXT is used, the full-text query engine internally performs
>   the following actions on the freetext_string, assigns each term a
>   weight, and then finds the matches:
>
> - **Separates the string into individual words based on word boundaries (word-breaking).**
> - Generates inflectional forms of the words (stemming).
> - Identifies a list of expansions or replacements for the terms based on matches in the thesaurus.

Again, emphasis my own.

A value like `'abaycant'` doesn't have any word boundaries, so `FREETEXT(title, 'baycan')` will not work. If you need a leading wildcard, due to the need to search **within** a word, you cannot utilise a Full Text Search, as an FTS indexes the words, not the characters.